MySQL full-text search with aggregate functions
I have a website connected to a MySQL database of songs, and am working to improve full-text search on the site. A simple query with MATCH() works as expected, but as soon as I add an aggregate function to the SELECT statement, MATCH() no longer returns relevant results.
The query I'm using is somewhat complicated, but I was able to boil it down to a minimal example:

Create a table with an FTS index, and insert three songs:

CREATE TABLE `Song` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTS_Songs` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO Song (`title`)
VALUES ('The Morning Breaks'), ('The Spirit of God'), ('Now Let Us Rejoice');


Run a simple query with MATCH(). This works correctly, bringing the most relevant song (“The Spirit of God”) to the top:

SELECT id, title,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"the spirit of god"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS exactTitleRelevance,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+spirit* +god*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleRelevance
FROM Song
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY exactTitleRelevance DESC, titleRelevance DESC;

Correct result:
The row for "The Spirit of God" has a high relevance score, and other rows have a relevance of 0.


Add any aggregate function (my real query has a GROUP_CONCAT() to aggregate data from a joined table; in this example, I’m using COUNT() without any joins for simplicity). This does not work correctly. As soon as I add an aggregate function, MATCH() breaks and returns inaccurate results:

SELECT id, title,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"the spirit of god"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS exactTitleRelevance,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+spirit* +god*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleRelevance,
  COUNT(*) AS aggregateColumn
FROM Song
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY exactTitleRelevance DESC, titleRelevance DESC;

Incorrect result:
The row for "The Spirit of God" has a relevance score of 0, and a different row that doesn't match the query has a high relevance score.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use MATCH() and aggregate functions like COUNT() or GROUP_CONCAT() together in the same query?
I’ve tried and gotten the same results on two different servers – one with MySQL 8.0.37, and the other with MySQL 8.3.0.

Why are you using aggregation on the primary key? The "groups" will by definition be exactly 1 row.

@BillKarwin, my original query (a complicated 40-line query) has JOINs and uses GROUP_CONCAT() to get aggregated values from the joined tables. I simplified the query to a minimum reproducible example using only one table for this question. The same problem occurs in my original 40-line query and in this simple example query.

This bug report appears to be the same problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=114666. The MySQL verification team has reproduced the bug using MySQL 8.0.36, but there is no fix mentioned. I suggest you log into that bug site and click the "Affects Me" button.

what is you expected result @SamuelBradshaw ?

@ArtBindu, I expect to see "The Spirit of God" (hymn 2) have a high relevance score from the MATCH() function. Instead, the MATCH() function gives it a score of 0.

@SamuelBradshaw your query is COUNT(*) on GROUP BY id and it's returning expected result 1 1 1 as all occurrence of all id are 1. So, aggregateColumn column value is right according to you query ... I don't understand what issue with SQL count() function. There are no other condition with SQL  count() function. Please simplify your question and add an expected result ...

@ArtBindu, the aggregateColumn is returning correct values. exactTitleRelevance and titleRelevance are returning incorrect values. In the question (step 2), I show the values I expect for each row. I expect the row "The Spirit of God" to have a number other than 0 in the exactTitleRelevance and titleRelevance columns.

You can use EXPLAIN to check how MySQL executes the query:
EXPLAIN SELECT id, title,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"the spirit of god"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS exactTitleRelevance,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+spirit* +god*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleRelevance,
  COUNT(*) AS aggregateColumn
FROM Song
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY exactTitleRelevance DESC, titleRelevance DESC;

This will give:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
Song
NULL
index
PRIMARY,FTS_Songs
PRIMARY
4
NULL
3
100.00
Using temporary; Using filesort



The aggregate function COUNT() along with GROUP BY changes how MySQL processes the query. MySQL uses "id" (PRIMARY) as an index instead of FTS_Songs (FULLTEXT) causing MATCH() to not work as expected.
To make sure MATCH() calculates relevance accurately:

Use CTE/subquery to perform the full-text search first.
Then apply any aggregate functions.

e.g.
WITH lookup AS (
SELECT 
  id,
  title,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"the spirit of god"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS exactTitleRelevance,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+spirit* +god*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleRelevance
FROM Song
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"the spirit of god"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
SELECT 
  l.id, 
  l.title,
  l.exactTitleRelevance,
  l.titleRelevance,
  COUNT(*) AS aggregateColumn
FROM  lookup l
GROUP BY  l.id,  l.title, l.exactTitleRelevance,  l.titleRelevance;


Learn new thing in MySQL, EXPLAIN statement ...
